# Laravel route function with multiple params

Tags: php, laravel

```php
Route::get('/storage/image/{file}', function ($file,$dir="products") { 
    return response()->file(storage_path("app/images/$dir/$file")); 
})->name("storageImg");
```

`$file` to get image file name, `$dir` to get image directory like `app/images/productes`

i want to use `$dir` param like this

```php
{{route("storageImg", ["file" => "fileName", "dir" = >"file Directory Name"])}}
```

Comment: would using `/storage/image/{file}/{dir}/{extra}` work?

Comment: What is your question? Why make `$dir` a parameter when it's not in the route?

Comment: $file to get image file name,
$dir to get image directory like app/images/productes

Comment: 1- your question is not clean....


2- use like this : `{{ route("storageImg",[$file, $dir]) }}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
Route::get('/storage/image/{file}/{dir}', function ($file,$dir="products") { 
    return response()->file(storage_path("app/images/$dir/$file")); 
})->name("storageImg");
```

Comment: Route parameters don't have `$`

Comment: Yes . I fixed it